# how to select and copy a range from another workbook in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which allow me to copy and paste data into filtered cells only in the active sheet. but I want to copy the range from another workbook so please have a look into my code and help me to select the range from another workbooks

```
Sub CopyAndPasteOnFiltered Cells ()

Dim rng1 As Range

Dim rng2 As Range

Dim Input Rng As Range

Dim OutRng As Range

xTitleId = "Paste on Filtered Rows"

Set Input Rng Application. Selection

Set InputRng = Application. InputBox ("Copy Range :", xTitleId, InputRng. Address, Type:=8)

Set OutRng = Application. InputBox ("Paste Range:", xTitleId, Type:=8)

For Each rng1 In Input Rng

rngl.Copy

For Each rng2 In OutRng

If rng2.EntireRow.RowHeight > 0 Then

rng2. PasteSpecial

Set OutRng = rng2.Offset (1).Resize (OutRng.Rows.Count)

Exit For

End If

CopyAndPasteOnFiltered Cells

Next

Next

Application. Cut CopyMode = False

End Sub
```

thanks

Comment: dear Tom Brunber
Code was working fine because I had proper indentation in the VBA editor... just help me out with the thing I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Workbooks object like this:

```
Application.Workbooks("The name of your workbook you want to work with...").WorkSheets("The worksheet index you want to work with...").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Hi Darren, I deal with different workbooks that's why I am looking for a way like when we 'table array' in VLOOKUP, it automatically detects the workbook/ sheet name and we just have to select the range.... let me know if it is possible with my code